# Hexagon BCEGHJ surrounded by the rectangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

What is $m+n$ if $sin^2 \theta = \frac{m}{n}$?

Comment: There are $6$ questions, which seem like a graded assignment, or you're just dumping the questions on this site, showing no effort on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. Draw the $AF$ diagonal, write the angles, e.g. $\angle FEG=30^\circ$. Then conclude that $\theta=45^\circ+30^\circ$.
2. $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\,\cos y+\cos x\,\sin y$.
3. $\sin 45^\circ=1/\sqrt 2=\cos 45^\circ$, $\ \sin 30^\circ=1/2$, $\ \cos 30^\circ=\sqrt3/2$.

Comment: form where we can make it sure that $\theta$ is $45^∘$

Comment: $\theta$ is $75^\circ$. I used only that the sum of angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$.